# Python selenium click on button if it appears on screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So, there is a site that gets generated by javascript. And updates every second. And I want to get the values every second. But the site will pop up a modal asking "Are you still here". And then you need to click the button. So first my code looks like this:

```
    try:
        button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(@value, 'Refresh Page')]");
        button.click()
        rounds = rounds+1
    except:
        rounds = rounds+1
```

But when I look at my browser, it still reloads every round, even tho it doesn't show up in screen.

How can I make this work, to only click the button when it's on screen? Thanks!

Comment: can you change `find_elements_by_xpath` to `find_element_by_xpath` and try

Comment: Nope, it still reloads it every time @NarendraR

Comment: can you share the site URL ?

Comment: @NarendraR I think it's a typo, else OP would have got _AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'_

Comment: @NarendraR The url is https://www.rolimons.com/deals

Comment: @DebanjanB it's not a type, it reloads when clicking the button. So it can find the button and reload. But it's not on screen yet because its a modal that appears every 5 minutes or so

Comment: @AaronJonk I trust you misread **`typo`** as `type`

Comment: @DebanjanB That right there was a typo yes.

Comment: You you want to check whether page refresh modal present there if yes then click on refresh page. right ?

Comment: Yes sir @NarendraR

Comment: Please update the question with the actual working code. This code will not run because you can't do `button.click()` when `button` is a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the below code to click on the button once it available and visible to refresh the page

```
button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(@value, 'Refresh Page')]");

//To check button is present on page

if (len(button)>0):  

//And is displayed

if button[0].is_displayed():
      button[0].click()
   else:
      print "button not display"
else: 
    print("there is not refresh page button")
```

OR

```
// to check the dialog present here "show" is the class which retain by the div once the refresh button get enabled

if "show" in browser.find_element_by_id('timeout_dialog').get_attribute('class'):
   browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@value, 'Refresh Page')]").click()
else:
  print "refresh button not displaying"
```

**Note** : make the syntax correction as per python

Comment: Your indent is incorrect in the second half of your first block of code. The second `if` (and following) should be indented because it should be inside the first `if`. Also, python comments are # not //, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#an-informal-introduction-to-python)

Comment: @JeffC, Yep I'm aware of that's why i have added a note as there is restriction to post the plain code in my system.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't fix it??? You need to fix it or it's not correct, especially the first part.

Comment: That's kinda rude, yes? I can fix it but it's not my job to go around and fix everyone else's mistakes. I pointed them out to you... why can't you fix them? Do you usually have others come and clean up your messes? Your answer is wrong as posted, I pointed out the mistakes and you have refused to fix them.

Comment: You already posted the code, all you have to do is indent it properly. If you can't do that for some reason at work, then fix it when you get home. Either way, I explained why and where the answer is wrong.